# Finding the behavior of number of prime factors of $a_n$

Tags: limits, number-theory, solution-verification, factoring

> Let $a_1=2$ and for all natural number $n$, define $a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n+1)$. Then, as $n→∞$, the number of prime factors of $a_n$ are increasing indefinitely, increasing to a finite limit, decreasing, or oscillating?

The answer is not given to it in the worksheet I refer to, so I wanted to confirm my reasoning and answer.

***My Reasoning:*** We have $a_{n+1}=a_n(a_n+1)$, which means that all the factors of $a_n$ are also the factors of $a_{n+1}$. Also we know that $\gcd(a_n,a_n+1)=1$, which means that they share no common prime factors, hence $a_n+1$ must be contributing some other prime factors to $a_{n+1}$ which $a_n$ didn't contribute. This means that the prime factors for $a_{n+1}$ are increasing indefinitely (going to infinity) as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Please check whether the reasoning is correct, and if not, please provide another approach.

***THANKS***

Comment: This is spot on.  To be a little more explicit you have shown that $a_n \ge n+1$, which you can prove by induction.  Whether that is required depends on your audience.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for the response. Also, would this be 'rigorous' enough to be written as a solution if the question appears in some sort of olympiad (local level) style exam?

Comment: I don't know what the standards are for an olympiad exam.  If I were your professor you would get full marks for what you have written.  However, I was never a professor so I wasn't asked to determine what is an acceptable level of detail.

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh, anyways, thanks for the help.